# Lightning Process Builder Exception

Tags: process-builder

I'm trying to assign Contact to a new Opportunity using process Builder but I receive an exception every time when this process is running as below:

**Error:**

Encountered unhandled fault when running process Add_Contact_to_Open_Opportunities/301160000000EVs exception by user/organization: 005A0000001dibQ/00DA0000000Hmbg
Error

caused by element : FlowDecision.myDecision
caused by: The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Account.Id because it hasn't been set or assigned.

**Process Builder Criteria:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem in our org.  Move the lines of criteria about the "Account ID is null - false" & "Contact ID is null - false" to the first two lines of criteria.  I'm not sure the reasoning behind this.  We contacted support and had a similar error and couldn't figure it out.  When we put the boolean criteria in the first two lines as they suggest, the Process Builder worked with no errors.

Comment: I was having the same issue referencing an account field from a case. It was causing the error for all cases as it failed to evaluate the first criteria correctly.

Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd criteria is wrong. Change Contact.Account.Id to Contact.AccountId. It will work

Comment: is both are different `Contact.Account.Id` and `Contact.AccountId` ?